# how to separate columns of itertools.product to matrices/arrays

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a dataset of like 3 items e.g. `[1,2,3]`
I want to find the product of it with 3 repeats and then separate them into 3 datasets like this (it should be vertical actually):

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

I noticed that in python I can use iteration.product for finding products as:

```
data_prod=itertools.product(data,repeat=3)
```

now my question is how can I convert each column of the result (which the datatype is itertools.product) to 3 new datasets as shown in above example?

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip(*..)` to turn columns into rows:

```
dataset1, dataset2, dataset3 = zip(*itertools.product(data,repeat=3))
```

Demo:

```
>>> zip(*itertools.product(data,repeat=3))
[(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)]
>>> dataset1, dataset2, dataset3 = zip(*itertools.product(data,repeat=3))
>>> dataset1
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
>>> dataset2
(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
>>> dataset3
(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way, for display purposes, still using itertools.product:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

cols=['series1', 'series2', 'series3']

originDataset = [1,2,3]

data_prod = lambda x: list(itertools.product(x, repeat=3))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(originDataset, columns=['OriginalDataSet'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_prod(originDataset), columns=cols)

print df1

print '-'*80

print df2

print '-'*80

series1, series2, series3 = df2.T.values

print series1
print series2
print series3
```

Output:

```
   OriginalDataSet
0                1
1                2
2                3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    series1  series2  series3
0         1        1        1
1         1        1        2
2         1        1        3
3         1        2        1
4         1        2        2
5         1        2        3
6         1        3        1
7         1        3        2
8         1        3        3
9         2        1        1
10        2        1        2
11        2        1        3
12        2        2        1
13        2        2        2
14        2        2        3
15        2        3        1
16        2        3        2
17        2        3        3
18        3        1        1
19        3        1        2
20        3        1        3
21        3        2        1
22        3        2        2
23        3        2        3
24        3        3        1
25        3        3        2
26        3        3        3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]
[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
[1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3]
```

I hope it helps to, at the same time, learn how to use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org)